# Pass validation errors from service to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

In my web app i have service layer responsible for all logic (like registering, etc.). I wanted to implement server-side validation for my forms. The thing is i can't just throw an exception every time i catch invalid data, because if user typed incorrect email AND password, my service method would just throw exception as soon as it checks email, and password error would be noticed only after user corrected email and resubmitted form. I want my entire form validated at once. The important thing is: **i need only to pass error types, display messages must be added to ModelState in controller.** I have some ideas and i would like you to help me decide which one is better from performance and good-practice point of view (maybe none - maybe there is another solution superior to all posted by me).

Ideas:

1. Collect errors in a dictionary and then throw single exception
   containing all model errors in form of key-value (ex. "Password", "Must
   be >5 signs"). In controller i catch error, and read all entries using switch() to detect error type and add proper message to ModelState.

   - Pros: uses built-in Exception.Data dictionary
   - Cons: need to decipher error type from the string
2. Similar to previous, but i create custom exception class, which has additional field-enum dictionary (ex. "Password", ValidationEnum.LessThanFiveSignsError).

   - Pros: Enums are more elegant solution for switch() operations
   - Cons: need to implement custom exception to do something that built-in exception class could do actually
3. Custom exception with dictionary, but with exceptions instead of enums - i create classes like StringTooShortException and UsernameAlreadyExistsException and add them to dictionary (ex. "Password", new StringTooShortException()). Switch would probably need to check type object...

   - Pros: i use exceptions? the more i think about it the more i believe this is not a good idea...
   - Cons: pass objects Exception subclass (with all Exception class attributes and stuff) and only use information of what type is that object?
4. Make my every service method return custom class containing {object regularReturnValueDependingOnMethod, MyCustomErrorContainer canBeListOfEnumsOrSomething}. Basic difference between this and previous ideas is that i don't throw an exception just to carry my error container up to controller, i use proper workflow.

   - Pros: doesn't throw exception, just returns validation errors to controller, uses proper workflow to pass values
   - Cons: isn't it too much to wrap return value of every method just to pass validation errors back to controller? maybe validation error is exactly the kind of situation, where i should use exception to carry a message to controller (whatever that message could be: a text string or, in this case, an entire object)
5. Don't wrap return value, just create validation error container in controller and pass it to service as "out" parameter

   - Pros: simple
   - Cons: need to create error container instance before calling any service method (ok, just ones which validate input). is it elegant?

What do you think? Which one is best? I'm not interested in just getting it done. I want to get it done the way it should be done. I want to learn good programming behavior :)

Thanks for any help :)

//edit:
My latest thought: I could create another service method just for validation purpose (ex. method: RegisterUser() for registration, and ValidateRegisterUser() for model validation, i would just have to make sure to call validation method before i call regular method. What do you think?

Comment: Have you thought of using some libraries to handle validation such as DataAnnotations?

Comment: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hmm... I looked into it, but i don't think it would do. See, i'll need to perform much more complex validation, like checking if that particular user-to-user transaction could occur (check if no one modified ID's during form submission and does not execute operation on behalf of another user). To do this kind of validation, full access to service layer and repository layer is required. I am using Dependency Injection (Ninject) already so i would have to pass service instances from controller to custom dataannotation validator somehow.